# with jquery javascript play by scoll

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

hello all together i have this javascript insert at my wordpress vebsite and all its ok with src and all but the javascript show me this error

Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

https://jsfiddle.net/kmsdev/gsfkL6xL/  thets is the javascript code thets i use

hier at the jsfiddle.net more code

this code show me error

```
...........

$('iframe').each(function(){
LoadVideo($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

[image]

Comment: is jquery loaded when this piece of code is trying to execute?

Comment: ja it is but thets show this error  Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

Comment: That error is common when some code is trying to execute using jQuery before jQuery is finished loading. Try wrapping your code in `$(document).ready(function(){ /*your code here*/ });`

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){ 

$('iframe').each(function(){
LoadVideo($(this).attr('id'));
});

 });                 thets show the same error

Comment: After the page loads, try typeing `$` into the console and see if that throws an error. If so, try typing `jQuery` into the console and see if that returns an error. If `jQuery` works, replace `$` with `jQuery`

Comment: jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   $('iframe').each(function(){
   LoadVideo($(this).attr('id'));
});      i tray like this did you men like this  ? and thets show me this error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Comment: In the web developer console, just type `$` and hit enter. If that returns an error, then type `jQuery` and hit enter.

Comment: i tray it but after do this show me a lot of errors more then 1
    at Object.NewPlayer (autofillo.js:12)
    at Object.Init (autofillo.js:6)
    at LoadVideo (autofillo.js:56)
    at HTMLIFrameElement.<anonymous> (autofillo.js:68)
    at Function.each (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at a.fn.init.each (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (autofillo.js:67)
    at i (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)

Comment: the code thets i am using is hier  https://jsfiddle.net/kmsdev/gsfkL6xL/

Comment: You posted the stack trace, can you post the error message that goes along with this?

Comment: thets meack another place the errorr the errror lock licke this Uncaught ReferenceError: YT is not defined   

at this place is the code
 NewPlayer: function(){
            var _this = this;
            this.Player = new YT.Player(player_id, {});
            _this.Player.$element = $('#' + player_id);
        },

Comment: That error sounds like the YouTube API is not loaded when you you are trying to call `this.Player = new YT.Player(player_id, {});`

Comment: yes but thets work fine at the  jsfiddle.net what can be the problem about it or what can i do i am new in jquery world

Comment: Where is the javascript in relation to the iframes in the page source? Is it above or below?

Comment: ifram is in the post  but i beliv i know the problem but i don'T know how to sold it all the youtube url show automaticly this  &amp;wmode=transparent but to work this javascript nead to end the url ?enablejsapi=1   i beliv at this point is the problem  the Javascript is loaded to the head  and the youtube ifram is in a post list  of wordpress

Comment: Yes, this javascript needs to be loaded after the iframe. Put this javascript at the end of the page.

Comment: i tray to load at the footer.php

Comment: no thets dont help thets show the same errorr and the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to put like this . It will clear your issue. Please confirm that Jquery is loaded before this script

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
     j(document).ready(function(){
    });
```

Comment: var j = jQuery.noConflict();
     j(document).ready(function(){
$('iframe').each(function(){
LoadVideo($(this).attr('id'));
});
    });      i add thets like this  did i miss somthing 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Comment: sorry for not mentioning to replace $ with j. Please write code like this.`<script>
var j = jQuery.noConflict(); 
j(document).ready(function(){ 
j('iframe').each(function(){ 
LoadVideo(j(this).attr('id')); 
}); 
}); 

</script>
`